# PDF readers - algorithm for finding a word

Tags: algorithm, pdf

When one types `Ctrl+F`, how do pdf readers find the specific word/expression?

Is there an algorithm faster than linear seach to perform such a task?

Comment: Way too broad. There is plenty long articles on search and substring search in particular... Maybe your question is about getting text from off and not search at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It varies with different PDF reader, but I would guess that it was some known fast string matching algorithm (perhaps [Rabin-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm), [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm), or [KMP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)) probably run in parallel across all the document pages at once. For short text strings, this should be very, very fast.

And there is also high possibility that they use their own hybrid/modified algorithm of above algorithms mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

The speed at which a search algorithm can find words in a PDF has very little to do with the specific algorithm used and is far more dependent on what algorithm is used to determine what set of drawing instructions constitutes a word in the first place and what order they should go in. Some PDF creation tools will create an instruction that will set an entire line of text as a single instruction with spaces between each word. However, if any kind of non-standard spacing is applied to that line in the authoring tool, the PDF may place each word character by character with no spaces at all. Still others will try to avoid the memory burden of loading fonts and create the PDF such that all normal text gets rendered first, then all bold text, then all italic text, font by font. So if you just extract the text in the order it's drawn, you don't get the true reading order.

The better tools will take longer but will get this process right. After that, the time to search is trivial.